# Force A SharePoint Online Link To Always Open A New Tab In Chrome On Button Click No Matter In Which Browser The Page Is Opened In

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I need to force a SharePoint online link to always open a new tab in chrome on button click no matter in which browser the page is loaded in. Any ideas how to achieve that. Was thinking something probably with window.open

Comment: You could implement it using jQuery, but it takes a lot of effort because there are a lot of links, and you wouldn't want any link to open in a new tab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reply from chrome support team.

“I do understand the point you are trying to make about force opening a hyperlink in Google Chrome instead of the default browser. This feature is completely depends on the default browser which you've set on your computer. Currently, there isn't any option to open the hyperlink or the URL only in Google Chrome instead default browser.”

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xRGkUSITCAE;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/$20force$20a$20hyperlink$20to$20open$20using$20Google$20Chrome

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, and if there were it would be a major security vulnerability. window.open will only open another window of whatever browser the user is in. And most modern browser leave it up to the user whether that call opens a new window or a new tab. But to allow you to open a different browser, from a web page, would be to allow your web page to launch an executable on the local desktop and exercise some control over what that executable does, which would be very useful to people who want to spread viruses and/or malicious code.

Comment: I thought the same, although I found a script that works, but just for certain browsers, doesn't work with Edge and FireFox and I need for all browsers.

Comment: @BennyBlanco Can you please share the script that works for IE? I am looking for something similar and it would be really helpful.

Comment: Haven't tested this right now, but I think it was something like this:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("Internet Explorer http://www.google.com");
  }
  </script>

Comment: The Op asked specifically about opening Chrome from any other browser? You're solution might work in IE, but it definitely won't work in any other browser.